# How to make text appear on scroll React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my text to appear once im 100px above it, I want it to be hidden prior to that. I want it to slide in from the left at that 100px mark. I have never done something like this before this is new to me. How can I do it in React? I've googled countless answers and none have seemed to really help.

I tried using `this.test` and `this.test()` neither made a difference.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SlideIn extends Component{

    test=(e)=>{
        console.log(e)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.test())

    }


    render(){
        const intro = document.querySelector('.intro')
        return(
            <div>
                <p>text to be shown at 100px</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SlideIn
```

It doesn't log any event. If I `console.log('hi')` it will log hi once, but not anymore as I scroll?
I am using the test method, just to verify it is working.

any help, or videos/tutorial, anything is appreciated!

Comment: assign a function for scroll event handler, like this: `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.test)`. Remove `()` with test function.

Answer (score 2):

`scroll` is not the proper event to detect whether an element is being shown in the browser viewport.

To detect when an element entered the view box, you can use the `Intersection Observer` API which is available on most modern browsers. There is a React implementation of it: `react-intersection-observer` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer